# "An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'" error when trying to access the .mdb file

Tags: c#, connection-string, oledb

I am a Newbie to C#. I am creating a project where access file(.mdb) is located in a share folder and it is accessible to everyone. Now when I generated a connection string as

```
@Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="\\PC-NAME\DVA Share\\Folder\\SampleDB2.mdb"
```

But I got an exception.

> An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'

Could anyone help me? Are there any other attributes missing in the connection strings?

Comment: you really shouldnt share an access database like this.

Comment: Please show exactly the code used. That string is incorrect in C# because the single slash is the escape character

Comment: @DanielA.White that was my thought, but it is one of the ways recommended by MS, so perhaps they have fixed the simultaneous access issues https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74#bm3

Comment: Still incorrect, a share name is prefixed by two slashes \\PC-NAME\DVA....

Comment: string strConnect = "@Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\PC-Name\\DVA Share\\Folder\\SampleDB2.mdb";
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnect))
            {

Comment: Could you tell me how the connection string should for that shared path

Comment: The @ is outside of " ie @"Provider=...."

Comment: Thanx mate...!! You made my day !! :)

Comment: That provider is obsolete, please use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\\\PC-Name\\DVA\\Share\\Folder\\SampleDB2.mdb;"
```

OR

```
string strConnect = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\PC-Name\DVA\Share\Folder\SampleDB2.mdb;"
```

Then initialize connection:

```
var oleDBConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConnect);
```